# How to speed up query response time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, bigdata

There is a collection in the database, which has about 4.6 million documents.
(data structure can be seen in the screenshot.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

When trying to pull at least one value from this collection, the response time to the request reaches more than 3 seconds:
(And this is on my local powerful machine.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Work with the code request and response looks like this:

```
    // server.js
    const http = require('http');
    const { getProducts } = require('./controllers/currencyController');
    
    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        if(req.url.match(/\/api\/currency.+/g) && req.method === 'GET') {
            getProducts(req, res);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Route Not Found' }))
        }
    })
    
    const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 5000
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
    module.exports = server;


    //  currencyModel.js
    const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
    const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/');
    
    const findAll = async (currencyPair) => {
        try{
            await client.connect();
            const testingData = client.db('Trading').collection(currencyPair);
            return testingData;
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    module.exports = {
        findAll,
    }


// currencyController.js
const currencyData = require('../models/currencyModel')

async function getProducts(req, res) {
    try {
        const currency_data = await currencyData.findAll('EUR/USD');
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(await currency_data.find({id:1}).toArray()));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getProducts,
}
```

I suspect that the reason for such a long answer may be somehow connected with the lack of indexes.
(those numbers that are present are custom created.)

Question:
How can I speed up the response time from the server after receiving the request?
(preferably without using ORM and frameworks.)
And what should ideally be this time?

Comment: Try creating an index on the id field using 
`db.collection.createIndex(
  {
      "id": 1
  }
)`, if not already present, and then hit your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm editing my answer as per the insight gained though the comments.

The `findAll` method there is a bit of a misnomer, as it just is selecting a collection via the MongoDB driver. The problem is that you are triggering a table scan, that is, MongoDB has to go through every row in the database to see if it matches your expression id:1.

You can cut down the execution time by using `findOne` instead of `find`. Once a single record is found that satisfies the expression, it will return it as a result. This is usually not enough, as if the matching record is the last in the database, the performance will be the same as for `find`.

You should instead create an index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"id": 1})
```

Run this in the MongoDB console, or use MongoDB Compass to create an index. The example creates an index for queries using the `id` field in ascending order.

If you wanted to query for two fields, say vol and close, vol ascending and close descending, you would create an index via:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"vol": 1, "close":-1})
```

Comment: I can't delete the first line of code because this is method from other module currencyModel.js
That is not MongoDB method.
You can see the code of this module in this post.
http://joxi.ru/l2ZKbPRClXep0A

Comment: when you delete the line, on the third line, change `currency_data` to `currencyData` as per the example

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Dr8aZJySK9yVXm
Not helped

Comment: post the currencyModel file

Comment: http://joxi.ru/E2p3KO1HvDbB9m
here it is.

Comment: Ok, so you're not using Mongoose. I would:
a) use `findOne` instead of `find`
b) Create an index on your `id` field:
```
db.collection.createIndex({"id": 1});
```
You should be able to get results much quicker with either, and specially with both

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAg5e6oH5DG7ym
I think I have that indexes are generated automatically in my case.
Right now if I use this code:
http://joxi.ru/DrlK6ZoCKDzJvA
I have responses with 4ms and it is fast.
But If I need multiple data in my response - how should I do it fast?
How exactly should I do my response code?
(I mean mongoDb Query)